# One line graph array is truncating the x-axis for the rest of the data in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, linegraph

I am plotting lactate curves for a subject for multiple visits (eight in total). The data is formatted the same for each visit in a csv file and I've repeated the code for each line graph. When I go to plot these, visit #8 lactate curves will truncate the x-axis for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn')


plt.plot(S10.WL_V2, S10.LA_V2, color='black', marker='o', label="Visit 2")
plt.plot(S10.WL_V8, S10.LA_V8, marker='o', label="Visit 8")
plt.plot(S10.WL_V14, S10.LA_V14, marker='o', label="Visit 14")
plt.plot(S10.WL_V20, S10.LA_V20, marker='o', label="Visit 20")
plt.plot(S10.WL_V21, S10.LA_V21, marker='o', label="Visit 21")
plt.plot(S10.WL_V22, S10.LA_V22, marker='o', label="Visit 22")
plt.plot(S10.WL_V23, S10.LA_V23, marker='o', label="Visit 23")

plt.xlabel('workload')
plt.ylabel('lactate')

plt.title('S10 Lactate Curves')
plt.legend()


plt.show()
```

[Here is the plot with visit 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE0MC.png)

[Here is the plot and code without visit 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiCbm.png)

Hope you can help!

Comment: Maybe `S10.WL_V8` contains strings instead of numbers?

Comment: @JohanC, yes there was a string amidst the sea of float data in one of the other subjects for that time point. I removed that and it seemed to clear up the issue for all subjects. Thank you!!! That was driving me nuts.